# "Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts" Windows prompt

Tags: windows, git, command-line

I wanted to try and use `git` in my regular Windows prompt instead of in Git Bash. Simply for the reason that I could then use the terminal that IntelliJ provides. I figured it to be a 1 minute fix but I guess not.

When I try to `git pull origin <branch>` I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\Bitbucket\java-project>git pull
Could not create directory '/c/Username/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.167)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 12:8c:1b:f2:6d:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:xy:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/Username/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have set the permissions on the *existing* `.ssh` folder such that all Users have full access, administrators and SYSTEM. So that should be okay.

I also tried to run the prompt as Administrator to see if that was the issue but that's not the case either.

What I do notice now is that it says: `Could not create directory '/c/Username/.ssh'.`. However, my `.ssh` directory is located at `C:\Users\Username\.ssh`. I might need to change my configuration then.

**Git version:** 1.9.0.msysgit.0
**Windows version:** Windows 8.1

Comment: Does it work from the git bash prompt?

Comment: Yes, it works fine there. I've been using that for a year or two now.

Comment: That path '/c/Username/.ssh' looks funny, shouldn't it be '/c/Users/Username/.ssh'?

Comment: Yes indeed. I've noticed the same thing. I already created a file `C:\Users\Username\.ssh\config` which has the contents `UserKnownHostsFile /c/Users/Username/.ssh/known_hosts`. But I think `git` is confused as to where to find my .ssh folder.

Comment: Maybe you have HOME environment variable defined with wrong value in cmd.exe

Comment: That was indeed the issue. For some strange reason it was `C:UsersUsername`.

(How do I answer this question now?)

Comment: Turned my comments into an answer. But to make this question generally useful, you could tell *why* you had the issue, and *how* you actually solved it (for example in comments under one of the existing answers, or even as your own answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, tested with msysgit 1.9.2, when one selects to make just `git` command available from `cmd.exe` during installation (where other choices are, make it avaiable only under git bash, or make all MSYS commands available under cmd.exe), `git clone` works from *cmd.exe* prompt.

The ssh client uses `HOME` environment variable to find `.ssh/` directory, but *git* should take care of all the ugly details. You should *not* have `HOME` defined in your normal Windows environment, so if `echo %HOME%` in *cmd.exe* prompt prints a path, edit the OS environment variables and remove `HOME`.

If that does not solve it, uninstalling and installing latest version might help.

---

Finally, you have paths like `C:UsersUsername`, it probably means you're missing quotes somewhere. In *git bash*, try these two commands to see:

```
echo C:\Users\Username
echo 'C:\Users\Username'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you type your cmd session the **[`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat)** which comes with every [Git For Windows msysgit release](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases).

That will set your `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%`, which  should be `C:\Users\Username`.
But make sure you didn't have an environment variable `HOME` already defined with an incorrect value: unset it if that is the case.

Comment: Are you sure this is necessary? ssh  seems to work fine for me from cmd.exe without running this bat (latest msysgit release).

Comment: @hyde what is necessary is to check the current value of `HOME`: it will explain what is going on in the OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Git Bash console.
2. Perform the command below to enable read and write;
   chmod 776 your local path here/known_hosts

[More details here](https://alsdias.blogspot.com/2022/02/git-windows-failed-to-add-host-to-list.html)